# Ambiguous routes with MVC5 attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I am having an issue with ambiguous routes when using attribute routing. The problems stem from (I believe) using variable parameters at the root of our routes. What's vexing me is that literal parameters do not seem to be taking precedence, and MVC5 can't determine which route to use.

I've run into this before with other routes and thought I'd managed a fix by defining a convention route. With that in mind, where can I find more information on best practices for attribute routing, and resolving ambiguities?

Here's the code I'm having trouble with, as well as the exception.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.
>
> The request has found the following matching controller types:
>
> AccountController
>
> RoundController
>
> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.
>
> The request has found the following matching controller types:
>
> AccountController
>
> RoundController

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // I added this constraint resolver to resolve some other ambiguous routes that end
    // with a literal, but MVC5 wasn't able to determine whether to use those routes
    var constraintResolver = new System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
    constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("notWriteAction", typeof(IsNotWriteActionConstraint));

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);

    // This is the convention route I added to resolve another ambiguous route.
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Account",
        url: "Account/{action}/{GroupName}/{AccessToken}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", GroupName = UrlParameter.Optional, AccessToken = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

RoundController.cs

```
public class RoundController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("{groupid}/{campaignid}/{accesstoken}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TempRoundLink(string groupid, string campaignid, string accesstoken)
    {
    }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Account/ResetPassword/{token}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(string token)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the same trouble. I was able to resolve it by adding a negating regex contraint, but I don't think it's right. It will quickly get out of hand and become difficult to maintain.

Comment: Hi @JoshWheelock,
I need to apologize - I intended to write up the solution I found. I also went with a constraint to start, but abandoned that for something more maintainable.

I ended up stripping out all the Microsoft attribute routing we were using, and went with "Attribute Routing," which turns out to be an entirely different package.

http://attributerouting.net/

It's been working a treat!

Comment: @aholmes url is dead, current url is http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the updated link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I intended to write up something much longer than this, but I haven't had the time. The solution I ended up going with was to strip out any calls to Microsoft's attribute routing library, and to instead use the "Attribute Routing" package found here. http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/blob/gh-pages/index.html

It's been working very well, and the *Precedence properties resolve the exact issue I was having in my original question.

Comment: Updated. @chris-marisic commented with the updated URL above.

Comment: I can't believe I have to dump MS routing over this but this is the only solution I've found for this. Has anyone found an actual fix?

Comment: It's been a few years now, but if I'm correctly recalling what I found during my research, it's that the Microsoft library wasn't intended for these more complex cases, so I don't believe a MS routing solution is possible.

Comment: It didn't used to throw an Exception. I thought it was doing the right thing based on the literal part of the route I defined. Now it appears it was never doing that and I was just getting lucky with the route it chose. Now a bunch of my apps that used to work are throwing Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't quite what you're asking, but I think this can be fixed by using `RoutePrefix` attribute.  E.g.

```
[RoutePrefix("Round")]
public class RoundController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("{groupid}/{campaignid}/{accesstoken}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TempRoundLink(string groupid, string campaignid, string accesstoken)
    {
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("Account")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Account/ResetPassword/{token}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(string token)
    {
    }
}
```

I think the reason it tries not to make an assumption is because preference may not be always ascertainable.  E.g. how would you expect router to figure these two out:

```
Routes (from attributes):
"Account/ResetPassword/{token}"
"Account/{something}/alpha"

Reequest:
"/Account/ResetPassword/alpha"
```

but that's just a guess...

Comment: I was thinking `RoutePrefix` was my answer. Unfortunately, the RoundController actions all begin with a variable parameter and not "Round." I think leaving "Account" in the AccountController actions while using a `RoutePrefix` of the same method means the request URL would have to be "/Account/Account/ResetPassword/abc123."

I was hoping to use the `Precedence` parameter of `RoutePrefix`, but it seems that's no longer supported.

Comment: My thinking on the assumption is that literals should match first from the left. I'm sure there is a reason it doesn't do that, but I don't know why.

Your example would match Account/ResetPassword/{token} because Account matches the literal and ResetPassword matches the second literal. At this point, the literal "alpha" could not match.

Comment: If you need to maintain backward compatibility with existing routes, then yes, it makes it tougher. I a while back found one or two NuGet packages that installed functionality to allow tracing how resolution happens to help troubleshoot routing errors.  I don't remember the name of those though.  You can try those and see if they can give you insight into why it matches against your expectations.  Maybe it'll help find another approach or identify how to register routes appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like one was released in 2008. I'll give it a shot. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Comment: @aholmes Yeap, that was one of them, and this one was one I had the most luck with.  It did have a caveat that for some reason it didn't work for requests with .xml (or some other) extension, but would work for .json or any other arbitrary one (project was set up to ignore extensions altogether).  So keep that in mind that in case it gives odd behavior, modifying request in odd way may actually make it work (black art at its finest).